# How to delete List item from LIstActivity?

Tags: list, android-listview, listactivity, selecteditem, listitem

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(final ListView l, final View v,
            final int position, final long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


        final FriendInfo friend = friendAdapter.getItem(position);
        String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the item from the adapter, so how you do that depends on what type of an adapter your `friendAdapter` is. For example, if it's an ArrayAdapter, then it's really easy:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(final ListView l, final View v, final int position, final long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    final FriendInfo friend = friendAdapter.getItem(position);
    String selection = friend.toString();
    // do something with selection

    friendAdapter.remove(friend);
    friendAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If `friendAdapter` is some other type of adapter, then somehow you have to remove the `friend` item from the underlying data. After removing the item, you have to notify the list that the adapter has changed. For ArrayAdapter, that means calling `notifyDataSetChanged`, but for some other adapters it might mean constructing a new adapter and calling `setAdapter` again.

If you're not sure how to do this, show me the code where you construct your adapter, including the type of adapter that it is, and I can help you with that.